# node.js write directly to the socket underlying http

Tags: node.js

I have a **Node.js** `http` server that occasionally acts as a proxy for some server side code written in a different language.

So sometimes (but not always) `http` requests are to be passed through to an server application via sockets. The responses coming from the application already contain the http headers.

The problem is that I would like to simply write the application response into the http response stream without worrying about writing the headers and content separately.

I could implement the entire http server using net sockets but I would like to eventually implement a node http framework as the front-end.

Using the `http` module, is there a way to write directly to the underlying response socket?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will help - but perhaps looking into how socket.io/engine.io handles an `upgrade` request may good place to start? see: [engine.io.js](https://github.com/LearnBoost/engine.io/blob/433aa787b3ed64a3bc23bec6f4904f4fb567ec9f/lib/engine.io.js)

Comment: A reverse HTTP proxy is the most appropriate way to handle this -- [http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

When a request comes in, you should be able to access the `connection` property of the request.

```
var http = require('http');
http.createServer(function (req, res) {

  req.connection.write(/* your data here */);

}).listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:1337/');
```

Note that if you do this, you are also responsible for closing the connection when done.
You could also just pipe the two streams together.

Comment: after done writing make sure to call req.connection.end() for the response to be sent :-)

Comment: @Chandu, Good point, but do not call `end()` on the `req`, or the built-in code will send headers and what not.